# SQL query for selecting changes between 2 related columns in a single table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Is there a query that can select the rows where a change occurred between 2 related columns that hold different values?

To illustrate:

I have ONE table where there is an alphanumeric code, and another column to store its encrypted equivalent.

I need to find the rows where these 2 don't match. So if I have the following table "codes"

```
code | encryption
A1   | jl2
A1   | jl2
A1   | ki4
B2   | jl2
```

I want a query to select the rows where A1 resulted in ki4 and B2 resulted in jl2, because these 2 did not match to their usual results (A1 should always be jl2 and viceversa)

The codes are just examples of course, so I cannot just write a query that looks for these exact instances.

Comment: The problem is, how can you know whether the correct code for `jl2` is `A1` or `B1`?

Comment: Would there need to be some sort of "master reference" for codes then? if that's the case then I guess I won't be able to do this with sql.

Comment: I think a best way to formulate this would be.
"show me the rows where an X value in code corresponded to more than 1 Y value in encryption"

Comment: Essentially, yes. SQL can only give you a list of `encryption` values which don't match others for that `code`, or which match more than one `code`. But it has no way of knowing which is the correct `encryption` value for a given `code` value.

Comment: The problem with that formulation is that it won't select `B1` which has the wrong `encryption` value for its `code`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` to get a list of the rows that don't have matches:

```
select distinct code, encryption
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and
                        t2.encryption <> t.encryption
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in an answer, I think this actually got it done. Basically compare the table to itself once and then select the instances where the other column doesnt match

```
select a.code,a.encryption,b.encryption
from codes a, codes b
where a.code = b.code
and a.encryption <> b.encryption
```

Comment: How can the condition `a.code = b.encryption and a.code <> b.encryption` be satisfied?